# No mysqld or mysql.server after mariadb-server install

Tags: centos, mysql, mariadb

So... likely I'm an idiot, but I'm stuck. I just set up a CentOS 7 on Digial Ocean and I can't seem to get the MariaDB/MySQL server running.

Some output

```
[root@hostname ~]# yum list installed |grep maria
mariadb.x86_64                        1:5.5.37-1.el7_0                @updates  
mariadb-libs.x86_64                   1:5.5.37-1.el7_0                @updates  
mariadb-server.x86_64                 1:5.5.37-1.el7_0                @updates
```

So it's installed, can we at least see the client?

```
[root@hostname ~]# which mysql
/bin/mysql
```

Let's try and start the server, just for fun

```
[root@hostname ~]# service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
[root@hostname ~]# mysqld
-bash: mysqld: command not found
[root@hostname ~]# mysql.server start
-bash: mysql.server: command not found
[root@hostname ~]#
```

And this is where I get lost. Looking at what is actually installed, there is no server/daemon

```
[root@hostname ~]# ls -la /bin/my*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3419136 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/myisamchk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3290760 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/myisam_ftdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3277032 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/myisamlog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3320200 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/myisampack
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2914904 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/my_print_defaults
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3533016 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/mysql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  111587 Jun 24 10:24 /bin/mysqlaccess
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3089712 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/mysqladmin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3253112 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/mysqlbinlog
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 Sep  8 03:06 /bin/mysqlbug -> /etc/alternatives/mysqlbug
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3090832 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/mysqlcheck
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4247 Jun 24 10:24 /bin/mysql_convert_table_format
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   24558 Jun 24 10:24 /bin/mysqld_multi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   27313 Jun 24 10:24 /bin/mysqld_safe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3173968 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/mysqldump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7913 Jun 24 10:24 /bin/mysqldumpslow
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3315 Jun 24 10:24 /bin/mysql_find_rows
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1261 Jun 24 10:24 /bin/mysql_fix_extensions
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   34826 Jun 24 10:24 /bin/mysqlhotcopy
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3082072 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/mysqlimport
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   16204 Jun 24 10:24 /bin/mysql_install_db
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2923136 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/mysql_plugin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   11578 Jun 24 10:24 /bin/mysql_secure_installation
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   17473 Jun 24 10:24 /bin/mysql_setpermission
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3084760 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/mysqlshow
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3104240 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/mysqlslap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3442464 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/mysqltest
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2918416 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/mysql_tzinfo_to_sql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2995400 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/mysql_upgrade
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2913960 Jun 24 10:27 /bin/mysql_waitpid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3888 Jun 24 10:24 /bin/mysql_zap
```

Anyone care to point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Should anyone stumble across this, i found the solution here: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/43459/how-to-start-mysql-mysql-isnt-starting/

Repost below

---

To start MariaDB on Fedora 20, execute the following command:

```
systemctl start mariadb.service
```

To autostart MariaDB on Fedora 20, execute the following command:

```
systemctl enable mariadb.service
```

After you started MariaDB (do this only once), execute the following command:

```
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Comment: Trying `sudo systemctl start mariadb`, I get `Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`

Comment: `sudo systemctl enable mysqld` before `sudo systemctl start mysqld` did the trick, it seems.

Comment: thanks @donquixote I've never encountered that behaviour before (needing to enable before starting) with systemd. it looks like mysqld.service can be successfully disabled after starting and not stop the service. I want to explicitly start and stop the mysql service and not have it run automatically on boot.

Answer (score 17):

When you run:

```
yum install mysql
```

command by default it installs MariaDB not MySQL.

So try the following command:

```
yum list installed | grep mariadb
```

if `mariadb-server` is missing try this following command:

```
yum install mariadb-server
```

it installs the server package then start the service:

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

or:

```
service mariadb start
```

My issue was solved in this way.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer as of late 2016.  When installing mysql on CentOS it will install maria db, but it may not install the server (which is weird)  This did the trick.

Comment: Thorough and simple explanation, and it even worked! I am on the new Amazon Linux. Thanks!

Comment: @CraigJacobs I also had to install the server separately on Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 3):

The service name is `mariadb` so you can start it using:

```
service mariadb start
```

Stop it using:

```
service mariadb stop
```

And restart it using:

```
service mariadb restart
```

Comment: CentOS 7 is using `systemd`, so you should use the appropriate `systemctl` commands instead of the old `service` commands.

Answer (score 2):

See if `mysqld` is under `/usr/libexec/` directory. At least with CentOS 6.5 the usual MySQL installs the server itself there.

Also see the output from `systemctl list-units` to see the name for you MariaDB server.

Comment: mysqld is indeed present in the `/usr/libexec/` directory. However I don't see anything about MariaDB (or MySQL) in the output of the `systemctl list-units` command

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem trying to start the mariadb service

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

I figured the issue was in non-matching yum packages - some were installed from the [special mariadb repo](http://mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/) and others from the centos official repo. Thus I had to drop the custom yum repo entry, delete MariaDB packages and install mariadb-server anew, then the service would start without problem.

Comment: The output states `@updates` as the repo, so that doesn't seem to be the case here. This may still be useful to someone else, so thank you for sharing :-)

Answer (score 0):

@OP Please pick a best answer;
@Moderator please lock question;

Ran into this same issue, tried the other steps mentioned to no avail; what my problem was being logged in as root/sudo su, after exiting su and running `$ systemctl status mariadb` I recieved

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I then ran `$ sudo systemctl enable mariadb` recieving

```
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service to /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service.
```

Then starting mariadb with `$ sudo systemctl start mariadb` - No error/message so it should be good, but no harm in checking `$ systemctl status mariadb`

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-10-17 10:07:00 CDT; 5min ago
  Process: 18093 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18000 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 18092 (mysqld_safe)
    Tasks: 20
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           ├─18092 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr
           └─18261 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log --pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Oct 17 10:06:58 centos-7.shared mariadb-prepare-db-dir[18000]: MySQL manual for more instructions.
Oct 17 10:06:58 centos-7.shared mariadb-prepare-db-dir[18000]: Please report any problems at http://mariadb.org/jira
Oct 17 10:06:58 centos-7.shared mariadb-prepare-db-dir[18000]: The latest information about MariaDB is available at http://mariadb.org/.
Oct 17 10:06:58 centos-7.shared mariadb-prepare-db-dir[18000]: You can find additional information about the MySQL part at:
Oct 17 10:06:58 centos-7.shared mariadb-prepare-db-dir[18000]: http://dev.mysql.com
Oct 17 10:06:58 centos-7.shared mariadb-prepare-db-dir[18000]: Consider joining MariaDB's strong and vibrant community:
Oct 17 10:06:58 centos-7.shared mariadb-prepare-db-dir[18000]: https://mariadb.org/get-involved/
Oct 17 10:06:58 centos-7.shared mysqld_safe[18092]: 181017 10:06:58 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
Oct 17 10:06:58 centos-7.shared mysqld_safe[18092]: 181017 10:06:58 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Oct 17 10:07:00 centos-7.shared systemd[1]: Started MariaDB database server.
```